# How can migrate from springfox to springdoc in SpringProject(no spring boot)

Tags: swagger, swagger-2.0, springdoc

I have a normal spring project(no spring boot), I wanna migrate from springfox to springdoc
I know that springdoc is designed for spring boot but I dont wanna use spring boot
I is a lagacy project that work with Spring MVC and xml file for managing beans
thank you in advance.

I wanna get appropriate solution